# Can I remove this board between my joists to run a duct?

Tags: joists

Some of the joists in my basement have a board like this between them:

[image]

I cannot see how the board is attached - guessing it's nailed in from the side. Can I remove the board in question in order to run a duct in that space?

Comment: Only some of the joists have this board - called blocking in many areas?

Comment: That's right, only a few of them - many of the other joists have ducts running along them.

Comment: What size duct?

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate, probably 6" since that's what the rest of the house is using. This is for a ventilation unit, so fresh air will be going into that return duct further down the joist.

Comment: Are we to assume the duct you wish to run is parallel to your joists?  What is the size and shape of the duct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a 6" duct, I would just cut a hole in the blocking.

Blocking is there for at least 2 reasons.

1. To prevent the joists from twisting, which usually isn't a problem once the floor is installed.
2. To help spread the load and make the floor more rigid by tying adjacent joists together.

For these reasons, blocking is considered a good thing to do, though may not be done in all situations.

That's why I suggested cutting a hole in the blocking.  You maintain a lot of the benefit, but can still install your duct.

Comment: Thanks for explaining what it is, and why it exists. Armed with that knowledge, I am going to see if I can find another route to run the ducts that doesn't involve messing with any of the blocking. :)